# The method add(SimpleFeature) is undefined for the type SimpaleFeatureCollection

Tags: java, geotools, geotiff

I am trying to implement one program for vectorization where I have following compile time error. I am using GeoTools 14.4.

```
 private SimpleFeatureCollection assembleFeatures(GridCoverage2D grid, int band,
        boolean insideEdges, SimpleFeatureType type, ProgressListener monitor) {
    if (monitor == null) {
        monitor = new NullProgressListener();
    }

    SimpleFeatureCollection features = FeatureCollections.newCollection();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);

    Point2D p = new Point2D.Double();
    double[] bandData = new double[grid.getNumSampleDimensions()];

    polygonizer.add(lines);
    Collection polygons = polygonizer.getPolygons();
    final int size = polygons.size();
    try {
        float progressScale = 100.0f / size;
        monitor.started();

        int index = 0;
        for (Iterator i = polygons.iterator(); i.hasNext(); index++) {

            if (monitor.isCanceled()) {
                throw new CancellationException();
            }
            monitor.progress(progressScale * index);

            Polygon poly = (Polygon) i.next();
            InteriorPointArea ipa = new InteriorPointArea(poly);
            Coordinate c = ipa.getInteriorPoint();
            Point insidePt = geomFactory.createPoint(c);

            if (!poly.contains(insidePt)) {
                // try another method to generate an interior point
                boolean found = false;
                for (Coordinate ringC : poly.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates()) {
                    c.x = ringC.x + cellWidthX / 2;
                    c.y = ringC.y;
                    insidePt = geomFactory.createPoint(c);
                    if (poly.contains(insidePt)) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can't locate interior point for polygon");
                }
            }

            p.setLocation(c.x, c.y);
            bandData = grid.evaluate(p, bandData);

            if (!isOutside(bandData[band])) {
                builder.add(poly);

                if (insideEdges) {
                    builder.add(bandData[band]);
                } else {
                    builder.add(INSIDE_FLAG_VALUE);
                }
                features.add(builder.buildFeature(null));
                // here it gives error "The method add(SimpleFeature) is undefined for the type SimpaleFeatureCollection"
            }
        }
        return features;
    } finally {
        monitor.complete();
    }
}
```

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/jdeolive/geotools-old/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/raster/RasterToVectorProcess.java)

Actually I copied 2 classes `RasterToVectorFactory.java` and `RasterToVectorProcess.java` and the rest is my GeoTiff 14.4 Code where I have below error.

> The method add(SimpleFeature) is undefined for the type SimpaleFeatureCollection

Comment: Looking at Javadoc for [SimpleFeatureCollection](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/simple/SimpleFeatureCollection.html) and it's superinterface [FeatureCollection](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/FeatureCollection.html), I don't see any `add` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using following code as a workaround.

But the author who provided code on his website says the code will not work!!

```
 //features.add(builder.buildFeature(null));

 //add
 System.out.println("adding...");
 SimpleFeature feature = builder.buildFeature(null);
 ((Collection<SimpleFeature>) features).add(feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of SimpleFeatureCollection to DefaultFeatureCollection class

```
DefaultFeatureCollection features = new DefaultFeatureCollection("your_id",type);
```